# infinispan MarshallableUserObject marshalling error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, infinispan

I have problem with embedded infinispan marshalling in a dockerize spring boot application.
This method:

```
public  void incrementSmsSend( String key){

        AdvancedCache<String, DailySms> advancedCache=cacheManager.<String, DailySms>getCache("statistics-cache").getAdvancedCache() ;
        try {
            advancedCache.computeIfAbsentAsync("totalSms_"+key,s -> new DailySms(0L,null));

            advancedCache.getAdvancedCache().merge("totalSms_"+key,new DailySms(1L,null),(dailySmsInit, dailySms) -> {
                if(dailySms.isExpired()){
                    logger.debug("init numberDailySms: {}",dailySmsInit.getTotal());
                    return dailySmsInit;
                }else{
                    dailySms.increment();
                }
                logger.debug("numberDailySms: {}",dailySms.getTotal());
                return dailySms;
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Error:",e);
        }
    }
```

With this config:

```
 @Bean
    public InfinispanCacheConfigurer cacheConfigurer() {
        return manager -> {
            final org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration ispnConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .clustering()
                    .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).remoteTimeout(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .statistics().enable()
                    .build();
            final org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration ispnStatistics = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .clustering()
                    .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).remoteTimeout(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .statistics().enable()//.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
                    .build();
            manager.defineConfiguration("vdc-cache", ispnConfig);
            manager.defineConfiguration("statistics-cache", ispnStatistics);

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public InfinispanGlobalConfigurationCustomizer globalCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.clusteredDefault().transport().clusterName("vdc-cache-cluster")
                .serialization().addContextInitializers(new Bucket4jProtobufContextInitializer(),new ManualSerializationContextInitializer())
                .whiteList().addClasses(Tps.class)
        ;
    }
```

Generate this exception:

```
2020-07-30 09:19:09.981 - [vdc-ratelimiter-service] - [async-thread--p2-t5] - WARN  [o.i.PERSISTENCE] [] ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject'
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ericsson.vdc.ratelimiter.service.service.StatisticsService
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:353)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller.objectToBuffer(JavaSerializationMarshaller.java:44)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:70)
...
```

I use infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded version 2.3.1.Final and infinispan version 10.1.8.Final

Comment: is your class serializable? 
`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ericsson.vdc.ratelimiter.service.service.StatisticsService`

Answer (score 1):

I found problem.
In the Spring bean StatisticsService method incrementSmsSend used lambda expression so infinispan try to serialized all bean.
I create a BiFunction and change method in this way:

```
advancedCache.getAdvancedCache().computeIfPresentAsync("totalSms_"+key,new VdcSerializableFunction())
```

VdcSerializableFunction are:

```
public class VdcSerializableFunction implements Serializable, BiFunction<String,DailySms,DailySms> {


@Override
public DailySms apply(String s, DailySms dailySms) {
    if(dailySms.isExpired()){
        return new DailySms(1L,null);
    }else{
        dailySms.increment();
    }
    return dailySms;
}
```

}

Thank You